# Conditionally Add Body Class Within Module Block?

Tags: magento2, module, custom-block

I'm currently adding a body class in my module's default.xml but I can't (to my knowledge) conditionally add it within the XML file based on the module's configuration values. See this question -
 [Conditionally add CSS class to body tag](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133865/conditionally-add-css-class-to-body-tag) where they show that attributes don't support ifconfig.

**/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="mageziner-loading" />
</body>
```

However, I do **NOT** want this body css class to be added if the module is disabled such as `ifconfig="design/mageziner/enable_frontend"` **AND** when a config value is not equal to a specific value.

I'm currently conditionally loading a template by checking for specific config values within the block class:

**default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Gil\Mageziner\Block\Mageziner" name="gil_mageziner_sidebar"  template="Gil_Mageziner::sidebar.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**module's block:**

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if ($this->getConfig('design/mageziner/enable_frontend') && $this->withinSelectedGroup()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    return '';
}
```

**withinSelectedGroup()** inside module's block

```
 /**
 *
 * Does the current user match the whitelisted groups? (Logged out users have a group ID of 0)
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function withinSelectedGroup() {
    $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
    $whitelistedGroupIds = explode(",", $this->getConfig('design/mageziner/customer_group')); // string is returned with multiple group IDs seperated by a ','

    if (in_array($customerGroupId, $whitelistedGroupIds)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

of key interested is, *$this->withinSelectedGroup()* which if it returns false does not render the sidebar.phtml template. How would I add a body class if that value is returned as true?

Also, would it be possible to also conditionally load CSS/JS based on that value? Currently I always load the asset files which is NOT ideal.

Thanks for any help/insight. I've been looking around and can't find any solutions for Magento 2.

Comment: I went ahead and implemented an Event Observer and added a custom layout handle which only gets loaded if my config values pass. Seemed like the cleanest solution? I pretty much followed: https://gist.github.com/0-Sony/57de53857abb7245c9d4a902d8c57fe3